# Find the integration of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (10cos10t+20cos20t)^2dt$

Tags: integration

Could you help me to find solution of $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (10\cos10t+20\cos20t)^2dt$$

I have solution. But I did not understand why the term $400\cos10tcos20t$ disappear.
[image]
Thank you

Comment: $\cos n x$ forms an orthogonal sequence on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\cos 10t*\cos 20t=\frac{1}{2}(\cos 10t+\cos 30t)$$
$$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\sin 2x}{2}$$
$$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\sin 2x}{2}$$

Comment: Could you see my update. I don't know why the term cos10t∗cos20t disappear

Comment: @user3051460 integrate my first eqaution to see what happens